# CSS transform rotate property makes text disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am using D3 to add text to a `svg` within `div`, and then assign a class `label` to the text

```
d3.select('#myDiv').select('svg').append('g')
.append('text')
.text('myText')
.attr('x', xPosition)
.attr('y', yPosition)
.attr('class', 'label');
```

I then use CSS to style it

```
.label {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

The problem is that the text is invisible. If I examine the element with the console and deselect `transform: rotate()`, then the text reappears. When I reactivate the property, however, the text goes invisible again.

I have tried both with Chrome62 and Firefox55 and the behavior is the same in both browsers.

Comment: You are probably rotating it such that it gets rotated off the edge of the screen. You need to set the transformOrigin property.